# hover mouse over window and move mouse to resize window using autohotkey

Tags: resize, window, autohotkey, window-resize

I'm trying to creating a script that allows user to resize a window by hovering the mouse by pressing a keyboard shortcut without having to move a mouse to corner of a window each time.

This feature is currently available as part of [BetterSnapTool](https://youtu.be/qIyOJKy6wZk?t=150) for Mac OS X but I'm trying to develop the same feature for Windows 10 using AutoHotkey

I've developed a script for autohotkey that works well for most applications except for chrome and spotify (see below). It often gets stuck with the title bar menu open after hitting alt+space [see video here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7kyc4bidcsm86n2/2019-01-02_14-42-51.mp4?dl=0)

```
^+x::
MouseGetPos,,, hwnd 
WinActivate, ahk_id %hwnd%
Send !{Space}
Sleep 1
Send m
sleep 1
send {down}
Return
```

Is there a more reliable way can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this reliably by moving the mouse to the top right of the window next the minimize button and leaving the mouse button down while using blockinput.

Benefits:

- This allows the the user to move the mouse freely to move the window.
- It works for resizing as well.
- being able to move windows if they're snapped fullscreen.

TIP: script has to be run as administrator for blockinput to work...

```
;Move Window Mode
^+x::
KeyWait Shift
KeyWait Alt
BlockInput, On
MouseGetPos,,, hwnd 
WinActivate, ahk_id %hwnd%
WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
MouseMove, Width-186, 10
Click, down
Send {Shift Up}
Send {Ctrl Up}  
BlockInput, Off
Return

;Resize Window Mode
^+z::
KeyWait Shift
KeyWait Alt
BlockInput, On
MouseGetPos,,, hwnd 
WinActivate, ahk_id %hwnd%
WinGetPos, , , Width, Height, A
MouseMove, Width-3, Height-3
Click, down
Send {Shift Up}
Send {Ctrl Up}
BlockInput, Off
Return
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Sleep, 1` might not be enough time for the menu to appear on all applications.

The most reliable way to do it would be avoiding the menu altogether but that's quite some work to do through `WinGetPos`, `MouseGetPos`, and `WinMove`.

I guess you'll still be trying to use the menu, so my tip is to at least wait to be sure that the menu exists. You can do this getting the ProcessID of your hwnd, and wait so that first found window through that PID changes, that could be understood for us as a new window has appeared. In code means something like this:

```
WinGet, WinPID, PID, ahk_id %hwnd%
oldHwnd := WinExist("ahk_pid " WinPID)

Send !{Space}

newHwnd := oldHwnd
while (newHwnd == oldHwnd)
    newHwnd := WinExist("ahk_pid " WinPID)
```

But you'd need some better exit conditions in case that the menu didn't happen to appear (a timeout?) to not get stuck there.

Still after that the Sleep, 1 might not be enough.

Comment: Hmmm I think you're right about the menu being too slow.